# Restore mysql dump for specific table via PHP

Tags: php, mysql, restore

I've got a mysql table dump file (which can be viewed here: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=GQkjrDNz) that I would like to use to create a table (named php_blog_archive as per the dump file) using the contents of that sql file.

The problem is I don't have access to phpmyadmin, so I can only execute this via php command, I've looked at a few threads like this and the code I have thus far is,

```
<?php
// Config
$db_user = "username";
$db_pass = "password";

exec("mysql -u $db_user -p $db_pass -h localhost databasename < restoreold.sql ");

?>
```

But it doesn't work, it simply does nothing - doesn't even show any errors. Could someone please advise me as to how to proceed?

Comment: First, add a return value to your exec to see if it's even getting executed, http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Answer (score 0):

First of all the command must be:

```
<?php
// Config
$db_user = "username";
$db_pass = "password";

exec("mysql -u " . $db_user . " -p " . $db_pass . " -h localhost databasename < restoreold.sql "); // Added an space before -h

?>
```

And second, you've right access to create/edit/append the file and exec command?

Comment: Wouldn't that output the database to the 'restoreold.sql' file? And yes I have.

Comment: The password must be directly with no space avter the `-p`. You could use something like `-p"password"` or `-p'password'`. But mysql expects it there.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the good old problem wit the password.

```
<?php
// Config
$db_user = "username";
$db_pass = "password";

exec("mysql -u " . $db_user . " -p'" . $db_pass . "' -h localhost databasename < restoreold.sql 2>&1", $output);

echo nl2br($output);

?>
```

This will end up in `mysql -u username -p'password' -h localhost databasename < restoreold.sql 2>&1`

The last thing is to echo the error masseges or something else to HTML. This is done via `2>&1` and the `$output` reference variable which will be convertet from nl (new lines will end up with `<br />`) to HTML and echoed.

Hope it helps and works.